# Doxygen - linking to external documentation

Tags: javadoc, doxygen

**Introduction**:

I have a Java source file where I override a parent class's method.
How you comment this for javadoc:

```
/*
* (non-Javadoc)
* 
* @see org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor#createActions()
*/
@Override
protected void createActions() {
    super.createActions();
}
```

...then javadoc knows how to link the referenced archived documentation (e.g. charsets.jar from http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api) in order to provide the inherited documentation so you don't have to write it again.

For instance, when I've referenced the org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor#createActions() above, javadoc have generated the following method documentation for me:

> void sqltexteditor.SQLEditor.createActions()
>
> @Override
>
> Creates this editor's standard actions and connects them with the
>   global workbench   actions.  Subclasses may extend. 
>   **Overrides**:
>   createActions() in TextEditor

**The problem**:
I am using the doxygen instead of javadoc (for many reasons which I'll not mention here).
Is there a way in doxygen to link to an external documentation, like in the example above?
If there it is, how can I achieve the above result by configuring and using doxygen instead javadoc.

I hope that my example described better than me my goal.

Comment: I don't know if this was available in 2012, but nowadys there is some documentation at the doxygen page about your problem: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/external.html

Comment: Valid link from @PowerStat  response:  https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html